# Keycloak 4.8.0 Error when choosing standalone-ha.xml as --server-config parameter

Tags: jboss, keycloak, jboss-tools

We have keycloak 3.2.0 working on Docker.
When we run it, we add the ARGS --server-config standalone-ha.xml

e.g
Docker run foo bar jboss/keycloak:4.5.0.Final --server-config standalone-ha.xml

Purely because we're running a few nodes to the same DB

Upgrading to 4.5, the documentation here: 
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_standalone-ha-mode

Says, also add 
--server-config standalone-ha.xml

However, when i do that (From version 4.0 onwards), i get

```
21:12:03,574 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.6.Final
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYSRV0191: Can't use both --server-config and --initial-server-config
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.assertSingleConfig(Main.java:395)
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:169)
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:96)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:352)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:320)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:593)
21:12:03,973 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0239: Aborting with exit code 1
```

Now, if i run keycloak WITHOUT --server-config, and i enter the container, PS AUX shows its running standalone-ha.xml as config. 
But thats because we are migrating from a DB which has 3.2.0 previously installed.

How do i enable and constantly make sure that standalone-ha.xml gets selected by passing parameter --server-config to choose the *-ha.xml configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem in Keycloak. **Using -c instead of --server-config helps.**

See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-9393 for more details.